# Simplified view for double-entry inventory transfers

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, query, view

I'm trying to get a clean view of a table showing product transfers between warehouses. There are 2 records for each transfer: a "FROM" record debiting the sending warehouse and a "TO" record crediting the receiving warehouse. The (simplified) data looks like this:

**Transfer**

| TransNo | ItemNumber | FromToDesc | Location | TransEachQty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 236393 | 176 | FROM | 1 | -10 |
| 236393 | 176 | TO | 3 | 10 |
| 236393 | 386 | FROM | 1 | -60 |
| 236393 | 386 | TO | 3 | 60 |
| 236393 | 659 | FROM | 1 | -14 |
| 236393 | 659 | TO | 3 | 14 |

I want to end up with a simplified one-record-per-transfer view like this:

| TransNo | ItemNumber | FromLocation | ToLocation | TransQty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 236393 | 176 | 1 | 3 | 10 |
| 236393 | 386 | 1 | 3 | 60 |
| 236393 | 659 | 1 | 3 | 14 |

I'm not sure how to get there from the table I'm starting with.

Recommendations, please?

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8d56f/1/0)

Answer (score 4):

Seems like it's pretty simple conditional aggregation

```sql
SELECT
  TransNo,
  ItemNumber,
  FromLocation = MIN(CASE WHEN FromToDesc = 'FROM' THEN Location END),
  ToLocation   = MIN(CASE WHEN FromToDesc = 'TO'   THEN Location END),
  TransQty = MAX(TransEachQty)
FROM Transfer
GROUP BY
  TransNo,
  ItemNumber;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8d56f/2)

If there are more than one FROM and TO per grouping, or the positives and negatives are reversed, then the results may not be correct.